# aluminum sulfate vs (NH4)2SO4 in Colloidal Coomassie Staining Sol

Tags: biochemistry, proteins

I have been interested in Colloidal Coomassie Staining to detect proteins in PAGE gel.

I found 2 different recipes: one of them uses aluminium sulfate, the other, (NH4)2SO4. I am wondering about sensitivities of these recipes, and other advantages/disadvantages compering these two.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3149902/

This article describes a recipe using aluminum sulfate.

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/elps.200305844/epdf

(NH4)2SO4 is used in this article.